# Font rendering issue on iOS 10 safari (mobile)

Tags: fonts, rendering, mobile-safari, ios10

Got this weird issue after upgrading to iOS 10.

The BebasNeue font has been rendered weirdly. Please have a look at the 2 screenshots below. Smells like a webkit bug, happened with Chrome on iOS 10 too. Anyone is having the same problem? Any workaround?

iOS 9

[image: IOS 9]

iOS 10

[image]

Comment: Hi! I work on the WebKit team. I'm very interested in more details of where you saw this. Please feel free to link to broken content here or send some to me at mmaxfield@apple.com! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, I just re-download the `.otf` font and convert it to `.woff` again and it worked. Seems like the old `.woff` font has some compatibility issue and broken in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which was corrected (mostly) by adding the font in *.woff2 format from [here](https://github.com/GitScrum/font-bebas-neue/blob/master/fonts/BebasNeue.woff2). This corrected the display for 99% of the site, but there are still several pages where it is not displaying correctly. I'm still looking into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've added "text-rendering: geometricPrecision;" in my css.

```
body, p {
    text-rendering:geometricPrecision;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I used `text-rendering optimizeLegibility;`, not exactly sure if this was the problem or the .woff font format, as others users pointed out, but I fixed it by changing the text-rendering and kept the same font files.